# C/C++-like macro #ifdef 0 way to comment off code in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, comments

In C/C++, using the macro like below to comment huge blocks of code is common.

```
#ifdef 0
//comment block code
#endif
```

Is there an equivalent way to comment off blocks of code in python?

Comment: Even in C or C++ (they are *different* languages) commenting out a huge code chunk is bad taste and bad jhabit. Don't do that. You need to keep your code readable at all time!

Comment: Smells badly like some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). As I explained in my answer, you should not comment huge blocks of code (even in C it is very bad practice).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there an equivalent way to comment off blocks of code in python?

**No.** Python has no preprocessor, and its translation phases are different of those [from C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/translation_phases). Please refer to [Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/).

I recommend simply appending some `#-` string in front of every useless line (and also use some [version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) system like [`git`](http://git-scm.org/) to keep older versions; then you might not even need to comment out big code chunks, since they are kept by your version control system).

Good editors (like [emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)) have facilities (like its [rectangle](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Rectangles.html) operations) to easily adding a string in front of many lines.

BTW, commenting out (or `#if 0`-ing it) a large piece of code is bad practice (even in C or C++), it makes your code unreadable. So **don't do that!**

If you use `git`, adding a small comment like

```
# many obsolete functions like foo and bar 
# have been removed after commit 670aaf569a7cc104e
```

is IMHO much better than keeping and commenting out hundreds of useless source code lines, and that is why I think that commenting out many lines of code is almost always a mistake.